# Characteristic functions proof... $\mu\{x:|x|>r\}\le\tfrac r2\int_{-2/r}^{2/r}(1-\varphi(t))\,dt$

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

I am trying to prove Lemma 4.1 (1) from Olav Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability:

> $\mu\{x:|x|>r\}\le\tfrac r2\int_{-2/r}^{2/r}(1-\varphi(t))\,dt$

From context, I believe that $\varphi$ is a characteristc function, and $\mu$ is a probability measure. The proof given by my lecturer (which differs slightly from that in Kallenberg) starts out okay:

> $\begin{align}\int_{-c}^c(1-\varphi(t))\,dt &= \int_{-c}^c\left(1-\int\exp(itx)\,\mu(dx)\right)\,dt\\
> &=\int\mu(dx)\int_{-c}^c(1-\exp(itx))\,dt\\
> &=2c\int \left(1-\frac{\sin(cx)}{cx}\right)\,\mu(dx)\tag{1} \end{align}$
>
> Recall that $\exp(iz)=\cos z+i\sin z$, so 
>   $$\int_{-c}^c \exp(itx)\, dt=\frac{\exp(icx)-\exp(-icx)}{ix}=\frac{2\sin(cx)}{x}.$$
>   If $|cx|>2$, then $\frac{\sin(cx)}{cx}<1/2$, implying that $\left|1-\frac{\sin(cx)}{cx}\right|\ge \frac{1}{2}.$

I vaguely follow everything going on up until this point, we use Tonelli and then remark on the integral at hand, but the conclusion drawn is something that I do not see at all:

> So, $(1)\ge c\mu\{x:|cx|>2\}$. Let $c=2/r$ to obtain the result.

What happns to the case when $|cx|\le 2$? I am not sure how we get from the remarks to conclude that "$(1)\ge c\mu\{x:|cx|>2\}$"?

Comment: I have spent two days trying to understand various proofs from this section of my course, and my lack of success has lowered my motivation and hope, but I would like to try again. This is a real trouble-area for me. :-(

Comment: It seems like you're more comfortable with the harder bit of the argument, which is a little odd. Anyway, given  that $\{x: |cx| > 2\} \implies 2\left(1 - \frac{\sin cx}{cx} \right) \ge 1$, by the usual comparson rules, $$\int_{\{x: |cx| >2 \}} 2\left(1 - \frac{\sin cx}{cx}\right)\mu(\mathrm{d}x) \ge \int_{\{x: |cx| >2 \}} \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \mu\{ |cx| >2\}$$

The full conclusion will follow on showing that $\int_{\{|cx| <2\}} \left(1 - \frac{\sin cx}{cx} \right) \mu(\mathrm{d}x) \ge 0$, which is not too hard.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Ah yes, thanks, after seeing the graph $\frac 1 t \sin t$, it is obvious. If you wanted to post an answer I will accept. 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2Ft)sin(t)+between+-2+and+2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case $|cx|<2$, the result follows by showing that the integral is non-negative, as per stocasticboy's comment.

To see this, by sketching the graph, it should be obvious that for $|t|<2$, the function $\tfrac 1 t\sin t$ is non-negative (see sketch on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2Ft)sin(t)+between+-2+and+2)).